# Format String as an hex value and append it in char array

Tags: java, binary, hex, decimal

I have the following code.

```
String test1 = "10";
String result = String.format("%02X", test1);
char buffer[] = {result.charAt(0),0x01,0x00,0x01,0x00,0x20};
byte[] bufferbyte = new String(buffer).getBytes();
for (byte b : bufferbyte){
  System.out.format("0X%x ", b);
}
```

Actually the string variable "test1" contains the decimal value. By this i mean to say that user can input 1 -256 integer digits and it is stored in "test1". I have placed 10 as the example . i need to append its hex value (0A) in char array, "buffer" at its first position and display it as an byte array containing hex value.

The above code is showing error as

```
"Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: x != java.lang.String"
```

Comment: if your test1 will contain integer, why it is declared as String?

Comment: `Integer.parseInt(test1);`

Comment: another part of the program is receiving it as an string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
    String result = String.format("%02X", Integer.parseInt(test1));
```

Comment: for test1 = "10" it is displaying "0X30 0X1 0X0 0X1 0X0 0X20 " whereas it should be displaying "0X01 0X1 0X0 0X1 0X0 0X20 " . i think it is displaying ascii equivalent hex value for 1

Comment: Java uses Unicode, not ASCII, but that is beside the fact. Do you want to convert the `1` to HEX and then the `0` to HEX or do you want to convert `10` to HEX?

Comment: you sure the first element should be 0x01? maybe it is 0x0A?

Comment: char buffer[] ={(char)Integer.parseInt(test1),0x01,0x00,0x01,0x00,0x20}; is this line ok. i got the result . but wandering how.. is it converted string to int and then to char

Comment: Integer.parseInt returns int (4bytes) char is 2 bytes so (char) truncates 2 first bytes of int

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SSCCE
{
    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        final String ten = "10";
        final Integer i = Integer.parseInt(ten);
        System.out.format("%02X", i);
    }
}
```

ouputs `0A`

You are trying to format a `String` you need to format the `Integer` representation.